# Ubuntu 16 when accessing virtual host showing Apache homepage

Tags: server, apache2

When I create a virtual host in Apache it shows me the Apache homepage and when I run systemctl status apache2.service, it shows this:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
   └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since منگل 2018-02-20 12:22:47 PKT; 14s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 1778 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 6568 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

When I restart Apache, it shows this:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

Virtual Conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.com
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com/public_html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Default conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

```
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Seems you have error in config. Edit your question and include virtualhost config. And default virtualhost config too if you changed it.

Comment: Done please review

Comment: Do you have a closing `</VirtualHost>` in your virtual host config?

Comment: Place closing </VirtualHost> and don't forget to enable virtualhost with `sudo a2ensite sitefile`. Make sure apache listens on address test.com if it have different IP. Check logs for configuration errors.

Comment: yes i do have clossing i forgot to mention

Comment: Site example.com and test.com already enabled